# GOLang: Extracting XML Issue

Tags: jquery, json, xml, go, extract

Hello StackOverFLowers!

I'm trying to extract the xml from the following.....
[image]

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "io/ioutil"
    "encoding/json"

)

type reportType struct{
    Course xml.CharData     `xml:"course"`
    Crn xml.CharData `xml:"crn"`
    Id xml.CharData `xml:"course>id"`
    Section xml.CharData `xml:"course>section`
    Title xml.CharData `xml:"course>title`


}
type myErrorType struct{
    TypeOfError xml.CharData `xml:"type"`
    Desciption xml.CharData `xml:"description"`
}
type reportTypeJson struct{
    Course string       `json:"course"`
    Crn string `json:"crn"`
    Id string   `json:"id"`
    Section string `json:"section`
    Title string `json:"title`
    course   map[string]string `json:"course"`;
}
func main() {

    baseURL := "http://turing.cs.missouriwestern.edu/classes/csc346/final/?crn=13398";


    var query string

    query = baseURL
    fmt.Println("The escaped query: "+query)

    response, err := http.Get(query)
    doErr(err, "After the GET")
    var body []byte
    body, err = ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    fmt.Println(body);
    doErr(err, "After Readall")

    stringOfBody := string(body[:500])
    fmt.Printf("TASK 1: The body(as text): %s\n",stringOfBody)

    //Unmarshalling
    var report reportType
    xml.Unmarshal(body, &report)
    fmt.Printf("The Report: %s\n", report)

    //Now marshal the data out in JSON
    var data []byte
    var output reportTypeJson
    output.Course=string(report.Course)
    output.Crn=string(report.Crn)
    output.Id=string(report.Id)
    output.Section=string(report.Section)
    output.Title=string(report.Title)

    //var output reportType
    //output.Version = string(report.Version);
    //report.Version -> output.Version
    //output.TermsOfService = string(report.TermsOfService)
    data,err = json.MarshalIndent(output,"","      ")
    doErr(err, "From marshalIndent")
    fmt.Printf("JSON output nicely formatted: \n%s\n",data)

    fmt.Println("CRN: %v\n",report.Crn)
    fmt.Println("ID: %v\n",report.Id)
    fmt.Println("Section: %v\n",report.Section)
    fmt.Println("Title: %v\n",report.Title)
    fmt.Println("Course: %v\n",report.Course)
    fmt.Println("ID: %v\n",report.Id)


}
func doErr( err error, message string){
    if err != nil{
        log.Panicf("ERROR: %s %s \n", message, err.Error())
    }


}
```

For Some reason it's not extracting the data from the file giving me basically a blank report. I made a program like this literally two days ago and am following the same format, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

OUTPUT:

```
The Report: {    }
JSON output nicely formatted: 
{
      "course": "",
      "crn": "",
      "id": "",
      "Section": "",
      "Title": ""
}
```

Any and all help is much appreciated, I have a test in a few hours and I'm hoping for some guidance by then!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml attributes on reportType to remove the root element: `xml:"course>crn"` should be `xml:"crn"`. If you aren't required to use CharData, I would also simplify your data types to strings so you aren't converting them later on. See my example playground for a working example.

https://play.golang.org/p/xysSV-7oCA